# What is the difference between "Needs details or clarity" and "Needs more focus"?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, vote-to-close

I am always having difficulty between choosing these options when **Why should this question be closed?**

Are there any good examples when one should be used?

Comment: Imo, their previous description was clearer, "Unclear what you're asking" and "Too broad"

Comment: It almost feels like it was left vague on purpose. I can't really guess why, though.

Comment: Hmm, it seems it is not only me. Interesting why SO made such a change.

Comment: @SuleymanSah - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337013/new-post-notices-rollout-on-stack-overflow (Basically we're all evil and there was a chance that someone could take offence to the old writing /s)

Comment: Frustratingly, the current options each better describe what the other old one used to.

Comment: Somehow the previous descriptions were easier to distinguish. Maybe with a a bit more time and training, it becomes easy for the new ones as well.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Needs details or clarity** should be used when it's unclear what op is exactly asking for. The best example are questions which explain a task, show some code but don't state what they want from the community or what there problem is. The close reason was previously named "Unclear what you're asking for" which was imho more descriptive.

**Needs more focus** (previously "too broad") is for questions where it is clear what op wants, but the scope of the answer would exceed the Q&A format. Example: "How do I write an operating system".